# Problemas con la propiedad background en el elemento boton

Tags: java, android-studio

en Android Studio 2.3 hice una pequeña App, la cual tiene un elemento botón con esta configuración, el botón funciona perfecto y la imagen aparece centrada en botón sin problemas.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/boton_opciones"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="opciones"
    android:background="@drawable/flecha"  />
```

Ahora que migre mi App a Android Studio 4.1 el botón funciona perfectamente, pero la imagen no se ve en el botón.

Comment: A esta pregunta le faltan detalles tales como: ¿Cómo es tu archivo `flecha`? ¿En dónde está ubicado?

Comment: Gracias por responder, la imagen flecha es un archivo jpg y esta ubicado en la carpeta drawable.

Comment: Bueno, vamos a probar de una manera distina. Quita la línea: `android:background="@drawable/flecha"` y en tu `activity`, donde esté el botón haces lo siguiente: `try{ boton_opciones.setImageResource(R.drawable.flecha); } catch (Exception ex) { Log.d("btnImagen", "error: " + ex.getMessage()); }` si la imagen no se muestra por algún error, desde el `LogCat` podrás visualizar el error

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, en el xml ya quite la linea, pero en mi activity.java no se donde colocar el código que me sugieres.

Este es el código de mi botón en el activity.java :   

public void opciones(View view) {

    Intent opciones = new Intent(principal.this, opciones.class);
    startActivity(opciones);
    finish();
}

Comment: No hay problema, debes añadirlo en tu `onCreate`

Comment: Franqo, ya pude solucionar mi problema, arreglando otro problema lo solucione. Colocando en el manifest.xml: android:theme="@style/AppTheme" para eliminar la ActionBar, las imagenes de mis botones aparecieron perfectas, no se que tiene lo uno con lo otro pero se soluciono. Muchas gracias

Comment: Que bueno que se te haya solucionado :)

Comment: Franqo Balsamo, ¿le puedo hacer una pregunta adicional aquí o tengo que abrir una pregunta nueva?

Comment: Lo ideal es que hagas una nueva pregunta 

Answer (score 1):

*Asegurate que esté cargada la imagen en la carpeta Drawable

*Si es una flecha, puedes agregar una desde "vector asset" que se encuentra con clic derecho en la carpeta ""drawable>new>verctor asset" das clic en "clip art" para seleccionar el icono que gustes.

Comment: Gracias Daniel, ya verifique y esta en la carpeta res/drawable/flecha.jpg. La opción de VECTOR ASSET es buena, pero la imagen que uso es personalizada y ademas no me pasa solo con la imagen de ese botón, también me pasa el mismo problema con otros 3 botones. y no doy que cual es el problema.